# Can I say an inverse function is continuous at point by the continuity of composite function theorem?

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

It is very common to find in calculus textbooks the following theorem: if the functions $f$ and $g$ are  continuous at $x_0$, then the composite function $f\circ g$ function is also continuous at $x_0$.

So, as we know that $f\circ f^{-1}=x$, can it be concluded that $f^{-1}$ has to be continuous?

Comment: No it cannot be concluded. The converse is NOT true in general.

Answer (score 0):

It can be proved that if $I$ is an interval of $\mathbb R$ and if $f\colon I\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ is injective, then $f^{-1}\colon f(I)\longrightarrow I$ is continuous. But this is false if, instead of an interval, $I$ is an arbitrary subset of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Ok, I am in doubt if it (this theorem) can be proved by another theorem which says that if two functions are continuous (say at an  interval $I$ of R), then the composite is also continuous, considering that $f^\circ f^{-1}=x$, where $x$ is known to be continuous.

Comment: No, it cannot be proved that way.